# Interpolating function error: stack trace value and notebook give different values for the out of bound inputs

Tags: interpolation, error-tracking

So, I get the input out of bound error, in the notebook out put.

""Input value {3.,1.5708,3.14159} lies outside the range of data in 
the interpolating function."

Values {3,Pi/2,Pi}. But the stack trace of this exact message only shows numbers that are different the the previous.

"Message[InterpolatingFunction::femdmval, {0.293333, -0.10472, 
-0.20944}]"

Does anyone know, why they would be different. For some context, the error is related to:

```
eq := f'[t] == ND[interp_func[x1], x1, x[t]]
```

And then solving it in ND solve. Suggests tags, I can't think of many.
[image]

Comment: I think it's the case where your interpolating function was obtained for a certain range of data say [0,2], and you are trying to find that for a point outside the range say 25. I would encourage you to put a minimal example that can reproduce the error.

Comment: @Rupesh I know that both of those points, are outside the range of data. My question is, why are they different.

Comment: Sometimes I know things, but often I have to figure them out. In this case I don't know, and it's impossible to figure out from what's given. But what is shown on the stack trace does not produce the message above it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiLnZ.png -- Further, the message indicates a function of three variables and the code indicates a function of one. That's confusing. `ND` does sample on both sides of $x_0$, so if you evaluate it on the border of the domain, you will probably evaluate the expression outside the range of data.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you Michael. I tried to simplify the problem because I was thought some information about the relation between the notebook messages and the stack trace, would be the most useful information for me to continue the debugging.

Comment: This will be hard to diagnose without a minimal example (as others have indicated).